# javascript(AngularJS)で配列の最後にpushができずに困っています

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

質問させてください。タイトルの通りです。
1個のshopに10個のlistが紐づいている構造の配列で

```
shop { id: "1", name: "shop1", lists: "Array[9]" }
shop.lists[0~9] { list_id: "1", list_name: "list1" }
```

に対して .push（もしくはもっといい方法があれば教えてください）で
shopに紐づくそれぞれのshop.listsの最後に、addvalue値を追加しようとしています。
以下のようなイメージです。

```
shop.lists[0] { list_id: "1", list_name: "list1", addvalue: "1" }
shop.lists[1] { list_id: "2", list_name: "list1", addvalue: "2" }
shop.lists[2] { list_id: "3", list_name: "list1", addvalue: "3" }
　　　.
　　　.
　　　.
shop.lists[9] { list_id: "1", list_name: "list1", addvalue: "10" }
```

whileを使って以下のようにaddvelue値をpushしようとしているのですが
"shop.lists[from].push is not a function" が消えずうまくいきません。。
原因の他にもっとスマートな書き方があれば合わせて教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
from = 0
to = shop.listTotal - 1  ## listTotalにはlistの個数"9"が格納されています
while from <= to
  # shop.lists[from].value = from
  shop.lists[from].push
    addvalue: from
  from++
console.debug article
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(CoffeeScriptのこともAngularのことも知りませんが) 配列なのは `shop.lists` であって、`shop.lists[n]` は配列ではありません。したがって、`push()` は使えません。

JavaScript 的に書くと、やりたいことは `shop.lists[from].addvalue = from` だと思われます。